# How to best create an abstract class for generic modelmapper management? To convert Entity and Dto for Spring REST API Application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I want to create an abstract class to be able to convert entities into dto and dto into entities with the modelmapper library. What am I doing wrong?

```
public abstract class AbstractConverter<Entity,DTO> {

    @Autowired
    ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public Entity toEntity(DTO dto) {
        return modelMapper.map(dto, Entity.class);
    }

}
```

This is the error

```
Illegal class literal for the type parameter Entity
```

Comment: Entity is an annotation not a class

Comment: In this case Entity is a generic object that is passed as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

The method signature must be

```
public <Entity, DTO> Entity toEntity(DTO dto) {
    return modelMapper.map(dto, Entity.class);
}
```

Comment: The type Entity is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Entity, DTO>

Comment: So Entity and DTO are classes, right? Then why do you have generic types on your class definition?

Comment: Entity and Dto are not classes, but generic classes. Specific classes are injected when AbastracConverter is inherited

Comment: Can you post the code of Entity?

Comment: I opened a new question with the complete code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69364258/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-entity-to-dto-for-spring-rest-api-application